# Passing javascript value to Twig

Tags: javascript, php, html, twig

```
$('table tbody tr  td').on('click', function() {
  $("#offer_model").modal("show");
  var index = $('table tr').index($(this).closest('tr'));
  var castedIndex = index - 1
  console.log("{{ attribute(offers, ??????).name }} ");
  $("#name").val("{{ offers[index].name }}");

});
```

I have an array of objects under offers array.I present the details of the selected offer in my javascript function.

In my click function I want to pass a calculated index (castedIndex) as a parameter to a twig template since the selected row is calculated with a JS. If i set castedIndex instead of ?, twig can not render the name of the selected offer.

Is there a way to cast a js value to TWIG?

Comment: You can't, you either transform the twig array to a javascript array or you get the correct value with ajax

Comment: What do  u mean with getting the correct value with ajax?

Comment: You create a controllers that fetches the `offers` with the same indices and you pass the javascript variable `castedIndex` towards the controller and return the according offer?

Comment: O I see. This not necessary because I already have all relevant information in the first Twig array.so only solution is converting the array to Js and getting the right object at the index?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. You could go with just something like : `var offers = '{{offers|json_encode|raw}}';`

Comment: @DarkBee Thank you for the tip.